# Accessing psql-array directly in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I am querying a psql database through PHP to get an array of boolean values where indexes are userids, e.g. `userconfirm bool[]`. When I do something like:

```
$query  = "select userconfirm from calendar where id = '%s'";
$result = $this->db->query($query, 2);
var_dump($result['userconfirm']);
```

I get:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["userconfirm"]=> string(20) "[256:258]={t,NULL,t}" } }
```

Which is to say I get a string where the array should be. Ok, parsing this could probably be done, if I studied up on PHP, but this feels wrong. Surely there's a way to get the array directly?

Main question is: How do I get this array to PHP directly?

Secondary question: Is this a suitable format for keeping track of user attendance? Is there a better way?

Comment: A quick glance through the [TOC of the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php) doesn't seem to bring up anything, so you may be stuck with parsing the string...  However, an alternative method for recording user attendance might be (using made-up column names, adjust to fit whatever you're doing) with columns of `user_id`, `date`, and `attended` (the last being boolean).  This form takes up more storage, but is easier to query.

Comment: @JackManey You mean create a new table? I've been toying around with that idea in my frustration. Perhaps that is the best solution, as my skills with complex queries is not the best.

Comment: @JackManey I think I will go with your idea. If you'll post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Re-posted from a comment by request)

Glancing at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php), it doesn't appear as though there's a way to directly interpolate a PostgreSQL array to an array in PHP.  However, if the position of your vector represents a user id, you might be better off restructuring your data to columns with `user_id` and `attended` (the latter of which should be a `boolean` datatype).

Answer (score 1):

PHP's native PostgreSQL driver does *not* support advanced data-types. In fact, it doesn't even properly support `integers`, `booleans` or anything else! (cite: As stated here under "Return Values", all values are returned as *strings*, NOT their correct data type: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php)

To help battle this problem, you may want to check out PHPG, a PHP library designed to specifically transform all returned PostgreSQL values to native PHP data-types. Supports arrays for any data-type, Hstores, Geometric data-types, and more:

**Numeric / Integers**

If you're a `numeric[]` or `integer[]` data type which does NOT have the possibility of containing NULL values, then you can simply remove the leading and trailing curly brackets, and explode the string into an array using the comma delimiter: https://github.com/JDBurnZ/PHPG

```
<?php
$pg_intarr = '{1,2,3,4,5}';
$vals = substr($pg_intarr, 1, -1); // Remove curly brackets
$vals = explode(',',$vals); // Returns: array(1,2,3,4,5)
```

**Strings**

However, the problem becomes much more complex when dealing with string-based data types such as `character[]`, `character varying[]` or `text[]` and here is why: If the value of an array contains a space or some other special character, then PostgreSQL returns that particular value encapsulated in double quotes. If the value is a single word with no special characters, then that value is returned with no quotes whatsoever.

Here is an example `character varying[]` value returned from PostgreSQL:

```
{val1,"val 2",val3,"val-4","val,4"}
```

The challenge here is:

- Can't explicitly explode on `","` because not all strings are double-quoted.
- Can't explicitly explode on `,` because a value may contain a comma such as `val,4`

The only method I was able to derive after MONTHS of encountering this problem over and over again was to take the string provided by PostgreSQL, and perform a subsequent query to UNNEST the array into a result set, which is then read and transformed into a native PHP array:

```
$grab_vals = pg_query("SELECT UNNEST('" . pg_escape_string('{val1,"val 2",val3,"val-4","val,4"}') . "') AS value");
$grab_vals = pg_fetch_all($grab_vals);
$array_vals = array();
foreach($grab_vals as $val) {
  $array_vals[] = $grab_vals['value'];
}
```

**Booleans**

In regards to `boolean[]` values, you could most likely take the same approach as suggested for integers. However because you also anticipate `NULL` values, we have the added task of mapping the string value `NULL` to PHP's native NULL data-type:

```
function pgBool2Php($string) {
  if($string == 't') {
    return True;
  } else if($string == 'f') {
    return False;
  } else if($string == 'NULL') {
    return Null;
  } else {
    raise new Exception('Mal-formed PostgreSQL Boolean encountered. Expecting value of "t", "f" or "NULL", encountered "' . $string . '"');
  }
}

$pg_intarr = '{t,NULL,t,f}';
$vals = substr($pg_intarr, 1, -1); // Remove curly brackets
$vals = explode(',',$vals); // Returns: array('t','NULL','t','f')

$vals = array_map('pgBool2Php', $vals); // Returns: array(True, Null, True, False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decided to go with a solution based on simpler data types, though. I suspect this is somewhat of an XY-problem.

Comment: No problem. The goal wasn't exactly to change or "win" the accepted answer, but to emphasize the overall underlying issue in detail. For whoever comes across this thread, I hope my answer shines a brighter light on the underlying issue. Eg: The lack of properly supported PostgreSQL data-types within PHP's native PostgreSQL driver.

Answer (score 0):

heres my [pg_parse](https://github.com/chandeeland/PHP-postgresql-array-parser) function on github